# arcgis developers - export data from FeatureServer into csv file

Tags: csv, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Good day to all,
I am new to survey 123 and argis online, but after loads of try, I ask for the help of the community.

**I am trying to export data from the API rest of arcgis under CSV format *by command line*. As I have hundred of Feature Layer to export, I do not want to download it through the "Export Data" button**

I have already download in json format through API rest, but the conversion of nested json into csv is tricky so I prefer to download the csv file from arcgis directly in command line.
For informations, the feature layer data that I want to export is from the results of survey made with 123survey.

Thus I have a table of data accessible to the following link : https://developers.arcgis.com/layers/6f8228f7bfa24a61a029aa9751da55d8/data/0

There is a tutorial in python to export csv from a layer, but in this tutorial the layer is a datasets, however I have a Feature Layer and not a datasets one :

- https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/python/download-data/

The documentation to query a feature layer is available to the following link, but we can only get html or json object from the query :

- https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/query-a-feature-layer/
- https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm

The documentation to export data is available to the following link :

- https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/export-item.htm

However I can not find the request to get the csv data from this table. I know how to do it through the web interface, but I want to know how to do it with requests.

I have already try the following requests with PostMan, but unfortunately none of the following have worked :

- `https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/home/rest/content/users/chargeetudeti/export?token=UsSMUWq.......&itemId=6f8228f7bfa24a61a029aa9751da55d8&exportFormat=CSV`
- `https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/chargeetudeti/export?token=UsSMUWq.......&itemId=6f8228f7bfa24a61a029aa9751da55d8&exportFormat=CSV`
- `https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/chargeetudeti/export?token=UsSMUWq.......&itemId=6f8228f7bfa24a61a029aa9751da55d8&exportFormat=CSV&exportParameters={"layers" : [ { "id" : 0 } ] }`
- `https://services6.arcgis.com/xNifwnpI45tLCPU7/ArcGIS/rest/services/service_70df166a7c9649878cc260d81ee85e4e/FeatureServer/export?token=UsSMUWq.......&exportFormat=CSV&exportParameters={"layers" : [ { "id" : 0 } ] }`

Do you have any clues ?
I made public the data to let you try to export the data into a csv format, from this feature layer : https://services6.arcgis.com/xNifwnpI45tLCPU7/arcgis/rest/services/service_70df166a7c9649878cc260d81ee85e4e/FeatureServer

I will be very gratefull if you could help me : )

If you think the title of this post or its tags, are not appropriate, please let me know.
Adrien

Comment: If you go to your item page (when logged in as the owner), something like https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6f8228f7bfa24a61a029aa9751da55d8, do you see an "Export Data" button with an "Export to CSV file" option?

Comment: Hi @BjornSvensson, thanks for your reply,
I do not want ot interact with the webpage through the 'Export data' button, as I have hundreds of surveys that I want to export.

Comment: The following [link](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/) shows command lines to download a Feature Layer and then export it into a panda data frame, which could be write into a csv file.